# reloadTable does nothing

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

i have a strange problem.
I have a tableview and a button where i switch to a modal view.
After dismissing the modal view, the tableview shall be reloaded.

For testing i just made a button that calls [tableview reloadData].
But nothing happens... And there is new data to be displayed.

Any tips would be nice !

My header:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController   UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
{

    UITableView *_tableView;
    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

My m file:

```
 @synthesize tableView = _tableView;

-(void) reload: (id) sender 
{     
    [_tableView reloadData];  
    NSLog(@"reloadData");
}
```

Comment: Is the tableView attached to the outlet (check if it is not nil)?

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but have you verified that the data has actually changed? reloadData might be working fine :-)

Comment: Yes, tableview is not nil.  And yes, the data has changed. i switch to a modal view and download new data, save it to core data and on next start of the app the table is filled

Comment: You might add a temporary timestamp output on a table cell to see if it's a refresh issue or not. cell.textLabel.text = [cell.textLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", [NSDate date]];

Comment: answer your own question below stating what you had done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i solved the problem.
In the modal view i save data to coreData. But i only read the data in the init function of my tableViewController!!  Now i have the readData function included in viewWillAppear and all works great. [tableview reloadData] just had no new data to display.